# Rotation of a 3d object around a 4th axis

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

> In maths we can define a unit vector that is tangential to the set of
>   3 unit vectors we use for 3d space. What would be the matrix operation
>   for rotation around this axis?

---

### Thoughts so far

(may or may not be relevant, or at all useful)

There should exist a rotation that if applied repeatedly rotates a unit cube through each of its rotational symmetries, whilst showing a different face each time. The justification for this is that it exists for 1d (scalar multiple of -1) and 2d (the matrix $\matrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0}$). There exists a number of matrices that satisfy that, but I think the one that is most similar is:

$A = \matrix{0 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0}$

Which in N dimensions is just -1 in the top right, zeroes in the rest of the first row and column, and then the identity matrix in the remaining submatrix (which could describe the 1d and 2d solutions). The inverse operation should be rotation about the same matrix by the negative of the same angle, and is:

$A^{-1} = \matrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 0}$

This implies the existence in $A_{12}$ of an operation for which $f(\theta) = 0$ and $f(-\theta) = 1$, that has range $[-1, 1]$.

---

Rotation by $\pi$ radians should be the unit vector. In 1d, rotation of ${}^\pi/{}_2$ gives you two identical lines, in 2d it's rotation of ${}^\pi/{}_4$ for the 4 rotational symmetries, so in 3d perhaps we should be rotating by ${}^\pi/{}_6$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a vector is "tangential" to a set of three other vectors? Do you actually mean a vector _orthogonal_ to the others? But that would not be what we usually think of as a rotation axis. The axes of rotations of 3D objects lie in the same 3D space as the objects themselves.

Comment: @DavidK, yes orthogonal. And yes, we normally do rotations around the x,y,z axes. What would the rotation be around a 4th axis $w$ orthogonal to the other three?

Comment: I don't think we can say "the" rotation around an axis in four dimensions. Generally you can choose any other axis in the 4D space and hold _both_ axes still, but depending on which other axis you choose you get a different set of rotations. Also, the only ones that aren't just 3D rotations or reflections would take most of the cube out of its 3D space entirely. There is no single rotation that will generate all the rotational symmetries of the cube.

Comment: @DavidK, The axis in question would be coincident with the unit vector $w=[0,0,0,1]$. A "rotation" (I'll stick with the term for want of a better one, though agree it probably won't look like a rotation as we know it) around the axis wouldn't change any values in that dimension, so a 3d object would stay in 3d space. This is much the same as rotation of a 2d object around the normal to the plane.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is _it does not work that way._ While a lot of things in lower dimensions have higher-dimensional analogues, many other things do not. Any rotation of the cube in which the cube ends up in the same 3D space it started it, is a rotation around an axis in that 3D space. The axis doesn't have to be the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis but its $w$-coordinates are all zero. The same rotation can also leave the $w$ axis unmoved as well, but that doesn't tell you anything about the cube's rotation that you didn't already know.